# Does curl vector influence the final destination of a particle?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, vector-fields, exterior-algebra, frobenius-method

If we have an $n$ dimensional space ($n>3$) with a continuous $n$-dimensional vector field $\boldsymbol F$ 
$$\boldsymbol F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$$

and for every particle in this hyper-space,

$$d\boldsymbol x=\boldsymbol F dt$$

where $t$ is time.

We assume that the origin is a stable point which means

$$
\forall t'>t\\
\boldsymbol x(t)=\boldsymbol 0 ~~ \Rightarrow ~~\boldsymbol x(t')=\boldsymbol 0
$$

According to Helmholtz decomposition (Helmholtz decomposition extended to the [higher dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100009/higher-dimensional-generalization-of-helmholtz-theorem) as well as [curl](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52829/)),

$$\boldsymbol F=-\nabla\Phi+\nabla\times\boldsymbol A$$

If under rule of $\dot x=-\nabla\Phi$, any particle at any location finally terminates to origin $\boldsymbol 0$

$$\dot x=-\nabla\Phi \Rightarrow \lim_{t\to\infty} \boldsymbol x=\boldsymbol 0$$

then, can someone conclude that, under rule $\dot x=\boldsymbol F$, the particles at any place terminate to the origin too?

$$\dot x=\boldsymbol F=-\nabla\Phi+\nabla\times\boldsymbol A \Rightarrow \lim_{t\to\infty} \boldsymbol x=\boldsymbol 0$$

In another term, does the curl part influence the final destination of the particle?

Comment: If $n>3$ then what is the curl?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I am not expert in math, but I just know that Helmholtz decomposition is [extended](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100009/higher-dimensional-generalization-of-helmholtz-theorem) to the higher dimension as well.

Comment: This question may be better posed to [physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Myridium, I am afraid that they give me -1000 and then kick me back as I am after higher dimensions ($n>3$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to be a rather trivial counterexample:

Set $\Phi = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$, so that $-\nabla\Phi = -2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\partial_{x_i}$. Its flowlines are given by $e^{-2t}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, in particular the $t\to\infty$ limit of any flowline is $0$. For $1\le i,j\le n$ and $i\neq j$, define the $(n-2)$-form $A_{ij} = (x_i^3 - x_i^2)\mathrm dx_1\cdots\widehat{\mathrm dx_i}\cdots\widehat{\mathrm dx_j}\cdots\mathrm dx_n$, where the hats mean that we take the product of all the $\mathrm dx_k$ except for $k = i$ and $k = j$. Then $\mathrm d A_{ij} = \pm (3x_i^2 -
 2x_i)\mathrm dx_1\cdots\widehat{\mathrm dx_j}\cdots\mathrm dx_n$, so that the corresponding vector field is $\pm*\mathrm d A_{ij} = (3x_i^2 -
 2x_i)\partial_{x_j} =: V_{ij}$. We therefore see that $V_{ij}$ is a curl (which of course follows from $\nabla\cdot V_{ij}= 0$). Then 
$$
V = -\nabla\Phi + 2\sum_{i=1}^n V_{i+1,i} = \sum_{i=1}^n\big(6x_{i-1}^2 -4x_{i-1} - 2x_i\big)\partial_{x_i}
$$
with $V_{n+1,n}:= V_{1,n}$ and $x_{0}:= x_n$ fulfills all the conditions of your theorem. Since it vanishes at $(1,1,\cdots,1)$, the constant path at this point is a flowline of $V$, and in particular this flowline does not converge to $0$.

Comment: I think by $V$ you mean $F$. There are also two unclear points for me. What and how does vanish at $(1,1,\dots,1)$?

Comment: Yes, you call this variable $F$. All of the components of the vector field $V$ vanish at $(1,\cdots,1)$ since $6\cdot 1^2 - 4\cdot 1 - 2\cdot 1 = 0$.

Comment: Tried to plot it. But, $x_{i-1}$ does not exist for when $i=1$.

Comment: I set $x_0:= x_n$; in fact any $x_i$ with $i\neq n$ will do. The point is that any vector field $f(x_j)\partial_{x_i}$ with $i\neq j$ has zero divergence and thus is a ``curl''. You can add this to the gradient vector field $-\nabla\Phi$ and force the result to have a zero somewhere which will give a stationary flowline.

Comment: This is true. But the point `(1,1,...,1)` is an unstable stationary point. Mathematica: `VectorPlot[{6 y^2 - 4 y - 2 x, 6 x^2 - 4 x - 2 y}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0,
   2}]`. Is there any example where the point is stationary as well?